# QuickBooks TxnID Format

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I'm looking to allow a user to enter either the RefNumber or TxnID into a textbox to query for an Invoice. What is the format for a TxnID?  I'm considering using a RegEx pattern to determine whether it's a TxnID or not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the QB OSR...

TxnID is of type IDTYPE
 An IDTYPE (identifier type) is a string with a theoretical maximum length of 36 digits, though the allowed maximum depends on the situation. An IDTYPE returned from QuickBooks is a concatenation of the object ID and creation time, separated by a hyphen.

Comment: Probably not 100% accurate, but we're using the following Regex to determine if a value _could_ be a TxnID: [0-9A-F]{1,26}\-[\d]{1,10}